# 555 timer IC unexpected pulse wave width problem in monostable mode

Tags: 555, monostable

I was trying to make a monostable timer for a specific project which should trigger output high for around 5 seconds. For that, I have chosen a capacitor of 4700uf and a resistor of 1K.

According to the formula of monostable mode (\$T = 1.1 * 1000 * 4700\$), it was supposed to trigger a pulse width of about 5 seconds,  but when I built it the timer pulse width is something more than 5 seconds, around 10-15 seconds

Here is my schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRFCaU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What mistake did I make here? Please point out the mistake with valid schematic if there is any.

Comment: Have you tried other capacitors and resistors to check if they give the correct timing?

Comment: Check if the component values are correct. Try different capacitor-resistor pairs (e.g. 22k - 220u, 47k-100u, etc.).

Comment: @HandyHowie i tried 1k resistor with 1000uf capacitor which was supposed to have a pulse width of 1 sec but actually had almost 5 sec, same problem just i mentioned above.

Comment: @Rohat i will let you know after giving it a try.

Comment: Are you sure you are reading the resistor colour codes correctly?

Comment: I am really sorry guys, after a lot of struggle, i found the IC malfunctioning, when I replaced that ic with another one, it's working fine, I am really very sorry for wasting your time.... Actually, i couldn't even imagine a newly bought IC can be a faulty one...

Comment: @HandyHowie yes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for wasting your time guys, after a close inspection, i found the IC faulty, when replaced with another one, it works fine, Actually, i couldn't even think that a newly bought IC can turn out to be a faulty one ...

Comment: That's good. You can accept your own answer do that the question topic does not remain open.

Comment: Subha Jeet Sikdar - As kindly commented by *Rohat*, you can accept your own answer but only 48 hours (or more) after you asked the original question (see [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer)). So please come back and accept it after that delay. Thanks!